# Getting TypeError when mocking interface in PHPUnit

Tags: php, phpunit, slim

I have a interface same as following:

```
interface UserRepository
{
    public function save(User $user): User;
}
```

I need to write a unit test for this function

```
public function action()
{
    $data = $this->request->getParsedBody() ?? [];
    $user = new User($data);
    $this->userRepository->save($user);
}
```

I try for mocking user repository interface

```
$app = $this->getAppInstance();
$container = $app->getContainer();
$user = new User(['a' => 'b']);
$userRepositoryProphecy = $this->prophesize(UserRepository::class);
$userRepositoryProphecy
    ->save($user)
    ->willReturn($user)
    ->shouldBeCalledOnce();
$container->set(UserRepository::class, $userRepositoryProphecy->reveal());
```

but return

> TypeError : Return value of Double\UserRepository\P1::save() must be an instance of App\Domain\User\User, null returned

i used slim-skeleton and phpunit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test case is missing but I'd guess that the user you're saving in your test is different from the one you used to set up your mock. For clarification:

```
    $userA = new User(['a' => 'b']);
    $userB = new User(['c' => 'd']);

    $prophecy = $this->prophesize(UserRepository::class);
    $prophecy->save($userA)
        ->willReturn($userA)
        ->shouldBeCalledOnce();

    $repo = $prophecy->reveal();

    $repo->save($userA); // returns $userA
    $repo->save($userB); // returns null
```

If there are side effects in your user that you can not control and do not want to get rid of, you may use a callback to check whether the given user is what you are looking for.

```
    $prophecy->save(Argument::that(fn(User $user) => $user->data === ['a' => 'b']))
        ->willReturnArgument()
        ->shouldBeCalledOnce();
```